# Performing arithmetic with assignment of named vector in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create new columns using the assignment operator in data.table, as existing columns divided by a certain quantity. The code I am trying throws a binary operator error due to the nature of the expression.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
DT <- data.table(x1=1:4,x2=5:8,x3=9:12)
DT[, c("y1","y2") := mget(c("x1","x2"))]  # works as expected
DT[, c("y3","y4") := mget(c("x1","x2"))/2]  # Error in mget(c("x1", "x2"))/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The column names are passed through variables, hence the character vector. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `mget`, we return a `list` output and the values in a `list` can be accessed with `lapply`.  So, we use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and then assign (`:=`) it to new columns 'y3' and 'y4'

```
DT[, c("y3","y4") := lapply(mget(c("x1","x2")), `/`, 2)]
```

However, the `data.table` syntax would be to specify the columns in `.SDcols`

```
DT[, c("y3","y4") := lapply(.SD, `/`, 2), .SDcols = x1:x2]  
DT
#   x1 x2 x3  y3  y4
#1:  1  5  9 0.5 2.5
#2:  2  6 10 1.0 3.0
#3:  3  7 11 1.5 3.5
#4:  4  8 12 2.0 4.0
```

---

This can be made more clear with creating some vectors and placing it in a `list` with `mget`

```
z1 <- 1:4
z2 <- 5:8
mget(paste0("z", 1:2)) 
#$z1
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#$z2
#[1] 5 6 7 8

mget(paste0("z", 1:2)) /2
#Error in mget(paste0("z", 1:2))/2 : 
# non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

while using `lapply/sapply`, we loop through the `list` elements and then divide by 2

```
lapply(mget(paste0("z", 1:2)),  `/`, 2)
#$z1
#[1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0

#$z2
#[1] 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! I did not think to loop through it as I didn't understand the source of the error. The first method, using `mget` worked for me. With the second approach, could you modify your answer to make it `eval(c("x1","x2")` if it is idiomatic? I had simplified the variable names in my question; they are actually not in sequence. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Naumz No the `eval` is not returning the value of the columns.  You need either `mget` or `get` (for one column).  If it is not in sequence, you can still use `.SDcols = c("x1", "x2")` or `.SDcols = c(1, 2)` i.e. the column index

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but `DT[, setDT(mget(paste0("x", 1:2))) / 2 ]` also apparently works. Or `DT[, .SD / 2, .SDcols = x1:x2 ]`

Comment: @Frank  Not sure if the second approach about dividing  `.SD/2` is more efficient

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know what happens when doing arithmetic with a data.frame/data.table.

Comment: @akrun in my case, `eval(c(.))` worked, but when I removed it, `c(.)` also worked. Also, the `lapply` method appears to be faster than directly using `.SD / 2` in my benchmarks.